# Can't set selectedIndex because tabBarController is nil

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to swift so sorry if I do it all wrong.
I have a view containing a tabBar and table. Here is my custom controller containing the reference to my widgets :

```
class NetworkViewController : UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tabBar: UITabBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
}
```

I'd like to set the selectedIndex in my tabBar. From what I understood, I can't do it directly on my UITabBar. I need a UITabBarController.

So I tried this inside the viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear methods: `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0`

Unfortunately, it does not work because tabBarController is nil.
How can I get a reference on my tabBarController ?

Comment: when are you doing this? assuming outlets are connected they won't be available till post viewDidLoad

Comment: Yes my outlets are connected (I have no issues filling the table or mapping the didSelectItem method for the tab bar). I was trying to set the index of the desired tabBar in viewDidLoad (and viewDidAppear)

Comment: Where is the tabBarController declared?

Comment: You have to create a tabbarcontroller, and set its delegate to self.

Comment: I dont have a tabBarController, would you mind showing me how to create it and how to delegate it to self ?